# Swift: vvmlog causing Cannot pass immutable value as inout argument: function call returns immutable value

Tags: swift

I'm using the `vvlog` function from the Accelerate framework. Here is the function. It explains itself better.

```
func logNX(_ n: Double, _ X: [Double]) -> [Double] {
    // Calculate the log base n of X.
    var Y = [Double](repeating: 0, count: X.count)
    vvlog(&Y, X, &Int32(X.count))
    var N = [Double](repeating: n, count: X.count)
    var Z = [Double](repeating: 0, count: X.count)
    vvlog(&Z, N, &Int32(X.count))

    return vDSP.divide(Y, N)
}
```

> Cannot pass immutable value as inout argument: function call returns immutable value

I'm not sure why. Am I supposed to go the roundabout way of creating an UnsafeMutableBuffer and pass the Y and Z arrays as data, then create an array and pass its pointer? This seems convoluted.

Comment: `Int32(X.count)` is immutable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to pass the address of an immutable constant. The simple solution is to assign `Int32(X.count)` to a variable and pass the address of the variable.

```swift
func logNX(_ n: Double, _ X: [Double]) -> [Double] {
    // Calculate the log base n of X.
    var C = Int32(X.count)
    var Y = [Double](repeating: 0, count: X.count)
    vvlog(&Y, X, &C)
    var N = [Double](repeating: n, count: X.count)
    var Z = [Double](repeating: 0, count: X.count)
    vvlog(&Z, N, &C)
    return vDSP.divide(Y, N)
}
```

Comment: I guess the count variable doesn't seem to require modification, which is why I had it as a const. Thanks for looking into this.